# Angular: NgAfterViewInIt getting called before ngOnIt

Tags: html, angular

We are using a hidden attribute on html side of parent component and its value is coming from one of its child component through subject. Now , in the child component ,where the value for hidden attribute is getting emitted , after that line , ngAfterViewInit triggers and only after ngAfterViewInIt has been executed , the code comes back to execute remaining lines in ngOnInIt.And after that It again runs ngAfterViewInIt.

In app component:->

```
<main [hidden]="pageLoaderFlag">
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</main>
```

In child component:->

```
ngOnInit(){
this.setpageLoaderFlag.next(true);
console.log('in NgOnInit');
}
```

```
ngAfterViewInit(){
console.log('in ngAfterViewInit');
}
```

I am expecting  in NgOnInit to be printed before in ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: Frankly that can't be true. Can you provide a stackblitz repro ? Because I failed to reproduce it !

Comment: You should place a console log before and after `setpageLoaderFlag` to have a better understanding of where code is executing.